# Socket read timed out in Oracle JDBC connection

Tags: java, oracle, sockets, jdbc, nullpointerexception

```
import java.sql.*;

public class OracleJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:TestDB";
        String user = "kdhong";
        String pass = "kdhong";
        Connection conn = null;
        String sql = null;
        String query = null;
        int result;

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("success!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("error1 = " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            System.out.println("success!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            sql = "create table testtable(" +
            "id int)";
            result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            if(result == 0)
                System.out.println("table created!!");
            conn.commit();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am using **Oracle DB 11g** and trying to connect it with my Java application program.
And I tried this Java code in my eclipse IDE. I installed **ojdbc6** in **jre/lib/ext** folder, and executed this program.
The class DriverManager was created successfully. But my code hangs on `conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);` statement. I printed the trace stack.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Socket read timed out
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:24)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:320)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
... 7 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:31)
```

I already checked out OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener service is being serviced. So what kind of other problems can cause this connection problem?